# Change position of values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, swap

I have the following multidimensional array. Need to switch the last value into position 3 and then push all the other values bellow that position.
The current array

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Vaccination
                [1] => Date of entry
                [2] => Animal
                [3] => Dog
                [4] => 246
                [5] => 4
                [6] => 984
                [7] => 102
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Vaccination
                [1] => Date of entry
                [2] => Animal
                [3] => Cat
                [4] => 246
                [5] => 4
                [6] => 984
                [7] => 118
            )
    )
```

Should output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Vaccination
            [1] => Date of entry
            [2] => Animal
            [3] => 102
            [4] => Dog
            [5] => 246
            [6] => 4
            [7] => 984

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Vaccination
            [1] => Date of entry
            [2] => Animal
            [3] => 118
            [4] => Cat
            [5] => 246
            [6] => 4
            [7] => 984
        )
)
```

This can be done with some function where in the future you can enter any multi array, position to be swapped and current item to be swapped. Can somebody help me solve the problem?

I tried the following and might have over complicated things

```
function arrayPositionSwap($array, $from, $swap) {
    $s = $swap;
    foreach ($array as $key) {    
        foreach ($key as $value) {
            while ($s < $from) {
                $temp = $key[$s];
                $tempBellow = $key[$from];
                $key[$s] = $tempBellow;
                if($s == $s-1) {
                    $key[$from] = $temp;
                } else {
                    $tempb = $key[$s+1];
                    $key[$from] = $tempb;
                }
                $s++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have __you__ tried to solve your problem?

Comment: Edited the post a bit. I am sure there are certain functions that can do this faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array slices and end of array to achieve the same,

```
foreach ($arr as $key => &$value) {
    $value = array_merge(array_slice($value, 0,3), [end($value)],  
             array_slice($value, 3,-1));
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/K1A9i)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Vaccination
            [1] => Date of entry
            [2] => Animal
            [3] => 102
            [4] => Dog
            [5] => 246
            [6] => 4
            [7] => 984
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Vaccination
            [1] => Date of entry
            [2] => Animal
            [3] => 118
            [4] => Cat
            [5] => 246
            [6] => 4
            [7] => 984
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `array_pop` to grab the last element of the array, and then use `array_splice` to splice it back in the third position.

For example:

```php
$out = array_map(function ($item) {
   $lastItem = array_pop($item);
   array_splice($item, 3, 0, [$lastItem]);
   return $item;
}, $data);
```

Outputs:

```php
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(8) {
    [0] =>
    string(11) "Vaccination"
    [1] =>
    string(13) "Date of entry"
    [2] =>
    string(6) "Animal"
    [3] =>
    string(3) "102"
    [4] =>
    string(3) "Dog"
    [5] =>
    string(3) "246"
    [6] =>
    string(1) "4"
    [7] =>
    string(3) "984"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(8) {
    [0] =>
    string(11) "Vaccination"
    [1] =>
    string(13) "Date of entry"
    [2] =>
    string(6) "Animal"
    [3] =>
    string(3) "118"
    [4] =>
    string(3) "Cat"
    [5] =>
    string(3) "246"
    [6] =>
    string(1) "4"
    [7] =>
    string(3) "984"
  }
}
```